# Which is the correct port for a SMTP Server with certificate in Windows 2012?

Tags: windows, email, ssl, windows-server-2012-r2, smtp

I managed to create and install a SMTP Server under IIS 6 in Windows Server 2012 R2. I set the port to 25 and I created a Windows account to authenticate to it before sending emails. Moreover, this server works with a RapidSSL certificate and it's set to use TLS. Anyway, I am afraid the port is not correct: should it be 587 or    465? What is the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 587 port would be used by mail clients sending messages (aka [`submission`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_submission_agent)). Whereas the 465 port is the one you're looking for (default `smtps`).

Comment: Ok, I will try to set the port to 465 because emails would be sent to it by our .NET applications. Jst to know, could port 25 with SSL/TLS cause some problems in sending emails? and, shouldn't it use TLS, then the credentials to access the SMTP server would be sent in clear, would they?

Comment: Not certain how it goes with Windows: I assume you may configure `starttls` on port 25. You shouldn't configure SSL directly on port 25 though: it would most likely prevent remote mail servers from relaying messages to your mailboxes.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will try with port 465 as you've suggested

Comment: You may risk login data being sent in clear. Clients should be configured connecting via smtps (+imaps/pops/...). You might be able to deny logins on plain smtp, yet you would still risk seeing clients mistakenly sending these, ...

Comment: Well, "clients mistakenly sending on plain smtp" should not be a problem because that account is used only as server relay in our .NET application to send emails. And the use of TLS is encoded the source code. It's not a "real" server SMTP but it's just used in web applications...